# chrome compute style error with transition

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, transition, react-router

Please click this link to see the error: [problem pic.gif](https://blog.azlar.cc/images/344be554-e0e0-e380-e09c-d0d4a28f6f66.gif).

This is an react and react-router app.

The left tags have a class of 'selected' (`background-color: blue;` and `font-color: #fff`) when clicked. When the post at right is clicked, the right panel will load the post and remove the class of left tag.

The `App.js`, right panel is in the `wrapper`:

```
<div className="blog" id="blog">
    <Header BaseOrigin={ BaseOrigin } />
    <Tags BaseOrigin={ BaseOrigin }  nowTag={ this.state.nowTag } />
    <div className="wrapper" id="wrapper">
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
</div>
```

The `router.js`(`history=browserHistory`) :

```
ReactDom.render(
    <Router history={history} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} >
        <Route path="/" component={App} BaseOrigin={BaseOrigin}>

            <Route path='article/:articleName' component={Content} />

            <Route path='tag/:tag' component={ List } params={{ tagMode: true }} />

            <Route path="*" component={ Test }/>

            <IndexRoute component={ List } />
        </Route>
    </Router>
    ,
    document.getElementById('qwe')
);
```

The CSS of `tag-block`:

```
.blog .tag-box .tag-block {
    display: block
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 7px;

    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;

    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.blog .tag-box .tag-block:hover,
.blog .tag-box .tag-block.selected {
    background-color: #38B7EA;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Error in Chrome : [problem pic.gif](https://blog.azlar.cc/images/344be554-e0e0-e380-e09c-d0d4a28f6f66.gif)

---

I have tried 4 ways:

1. remove class at `componentWillUnmount` of `<List />`
2. remove class at `onClick` at `<Link />`
3. remove class at `componentDidMount` of `<Content />`
4. add a callback in `App.js`:

   ```
   <Tags BaseOrigin={ BaseOrigin }  nowTag={ this.state.nowTag } />
   <div className="wrapper" id="wrapper">
       {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
           requestParent: this.setStateFromChild
       })}

   </div>
   ```

When the state of `<List />` is  updated it will call `requstParent()`, then the `<APP />` will `setState({nowTag: tag})` to pass a `props` to `<Tags>`.

All of them have the error.

---

Some things I have found:

1. When the `transition` in `.tag-block` us  removed, it works.
2. <s>add an `e.preventDefault()` in `OnClick` of `<Link />`, it works too, but could not route to article-page.</s>
3. <s>add an `e.preventDefault();this.context.router.push('article')`, it doesn't work either.</s>
4. It worked on Firefox.
5. On a MacBook Pro 13 it happened frequently, in Windows Chrome less frequently.

---

version in package.json

```
"jquery": "^2.2.1",
"history": "^4.0.0-1",
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1",
"react-router": "^2.7.0",
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue and I've tried numerous approaches to fixing it to no avail. Were you able to find a fix for this?  I see the correct render once I resize the browser...

Comment: sorry not yet...

Comment: Turns out that my issue is a new bug in the Chrome beta channel.  Reported it to the team.